# SQL join returns null records when there are no data in database

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get forum information and count of topics and posts. I am using mysql

```
SELECT forums.id, forums.url, forums.title, forums.description, 
       forums.icon, COUNT(topics.id) topics, COUNT(posts.id) posts 
FROM forums JOIN 
     topics 
     ON forums.id = topics.to_forum JOIN 
     posts 
     ON topics.id = posts.to_topic
```

But when there is no forum, no topic, no posts it returns
[image]

I´ve tried to use left join, right join, inner join (as I read on internet) but nothing seems to work. The left join works only if there is forum already created than it fills the data. **I need it to return no record if there is not forum created no this NULL nonsence.**
Here are structures of the tables, there are no data in database so I dont get why it returns this

Forums
[image]

Topics
[image]

Posts
[image]

Comment: *I need it to return no record if there is not forum created no this NULL nonsence.* This is your client program issue. Server does not return records - you may test this using console client.

Comment: @Strawberry I dont get whats wrong, I provided table structures, my query I am using, what I want to be the output, current output and what data are in database.

Comment: There's nothing to 'get'. Just read the accepted answer and follow the steps therein, or don't.

Comment: @Akina yeah it returns querry result filled with nulls thats just nothing basically. I require it to return nothing literally if there is no forum. Yeah I can do one query to check if there are any forums but I feel like it´s not good solution

Comment: Add `WHERE ... AND forums.id IS NOT NULL` - does the output changes?

Comment: @Akina Unfortunatly it doesnt, but I tried O.Jones approach with group by and it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending `GROUP BY forums.id` to your query.

You're mixing aggregate (`COUNT()`) operations with ordinary column operations in the same `SELECT`. If you give any aggregate operations and you don't give `GROUP BY`, you'll always get exactly one row back from the `SELECT`. In standard SQL your query will fail. MySql in nonstandard: it tries to guess what you want in the non -aggregated columns. If there are no rows to count it guesses `NULL`.

Read this: [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

In other words, as soon as you use `COUNT()` in a query you need to understand `GROUP BY` even if you don't put it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the `forums.id = topics.to_forum` need to be the same as you are connecting the tables together. It would most likely be `forums.id = topics.id`.
Same with this join, `topics.id = posts.to_topic`, it would be `topics.id = posts.id`